# Laravel Resource collection no longer working since upgrade to 5.6

Tags: laravel

I'm having the following code:

**Models**

```
class Document extends Model
{
    use OwnedByCustomer, OwnedByUser;

    public function document_type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(DocumentType::class);
    }
}
```

and

```
class DocumentType extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['name'];
}
```

**Resources**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class DocumentResource extends Resource {
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'document_type' => DocumentType::make($this->document_type),
            'description' => $this->description,
            'batch_number' => $this->batch_number,
            'size' => $this->size,
            'file_name' => $this->file_name
        ];
    }
}
```

and 
    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

```
class DocumentTypeResource extends Resource {
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'enum' => $this->enum,
            'name' => $this->getTranslations('name')
        ];
    }
}
```

And I then have a controller that does this:

```
class DocumentController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $query = Document::query();
        $query->withoutGlobalScope(OwnedByUser::class);
        return DocumentResource::collection($query->paginate());
    }
```

This is a common setup I have been using quite extensively, and without much issues.  For some reason however, the collection is not being wrapped in the json data property, and the links and meta properties are also missing from the request.
Also, the objects returned contain ALL attributes, even though I got rid of some of them.

I'm seriously lost as to what might be causing this now.  I've had this since 5.6, and am unable to find the cause.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: You might be using it through web routes not api routes. s per my understanding, laravel resources only works with api routes.

Answer (score 2):

Little late to respond but this actually fixed mine issue with ***withoutWrapping();***

**Just use these:**

```
 - use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource; 
 - JsonResource::withoutWrapping();
```

**Instead of**

```
 - use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource; 
 - Resource::withoutWrapping();
```